# C# Remote Desktop: Want to know the Client Device or Client Operating System

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, rdp

My Application is running on a Windows Server via RDP. In the Application I want to know if the Client (with the RDP-Session) is a Mobile Device.

Is it possible to get the Client Operating System?

Answer (score 0):

For a list of all RDP environment variables of the current user connecting please see the below comment.

The reg location for citrix ICA connections is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Citrix\Ica\Session\\Connection\

The Subkeys ClientProductID and ClientType will give reference to what kind of device is connecting.

Here is some basic code to get Remote Session and then get the sessions information from regedit.

```
  // Prints out ICA or RDP session ID of current user & gets ICA session ClientType variable

using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ViaRegedit
{
    class Program03
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Obtain an instance of RegistryKey for the CurrentUser registry 
            RegistryKey rkCurrentUser = Registry.CurrentUser;
            // Obtain the test key (read-only) and display it.
            RegistryKey rkTest = rkCurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Remote");

            foreach (string valueName in rkTest.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                //Getting path to RDP/Citrix session ID
                string RDPICApath = "";
                if (rkTest.OpenSubKey(valueName) != null && rkTest.OpenSubKey(valueName) != null) { RDPICApath = rkTest.OpenSubKey(valueName).ToString(); }
                Console.WriteLine("Getting CurrentUser ICA-RDP path from string = " + RDPICApath);

                //List<string> RDPICAnumber = RDPICApath.Split('\\').ToList();
                string RDPICAnumber = RDPICApath.Substring(RDPICApath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                Console.WriteLine("Current User RDPICAnumber = " + RDPICAnumber);

                //Getting reg local machine info for Citrix based on RDP/Citrix session ID "RDPICAnumber"
                string regLocal = @"SOFTWARE\Citrix\Ica\Session\" + RDPICAnumber + @"\Connection";
                RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
                RegistryKey citrixKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(regLocal);
                Console.WriteLine("Registry " + citrixKey + " Does Exist - going to get ClientType");
                //getting clietAddress var from citrixKey 
                string clientType = "";
                if (citrixKey != null && citrixKey.GetValue("clientType") != null)
                    {clientType = citrixKey.GetValue("ClientType").ToString();}
                    Console.WriteLine("Getting current user clientType from string = " + clientType); 
            }
            rkTest.Close();
            rkCurrentUser.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

You could easily replace clientType with ClientProductID and use the following reference  getting [ClientProductID information.](https://www.citrix.com/mobilitysdk/docs/clientdetection.html)

[image]

Comment: Thx, but I`m using a Windows Server 2016, not a Citrix Server.

Comment: Hello.  For a list of all RDP environment variables of the current user connecting please see the following commands. If looking for os type or connecting device focus on OS and CLIENTNAME but check for any differences in the printout would be advised between Mobile/Windows RDP connections.  `foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables(EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process))
            {
                string log = "\r\n" + de.Key + "=" + de.Value;

                Console.WriteLine(" {0} = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
            }`

Comment: Hello, I checked all the EnvironmentVariables. But i always get the Infos from the WindowsServer Session, not from the Real-Client.
OS=Windows_NT
CLIENTNAME doesn`t work for me.

Comment: So CLIENTNAME doesn't return any value when connecting from a mobile device ?   That is unfortunate.  Those are the most useful variables that windows RDP sessions provide.  Have you considered using Client Access licenses (CALs) ?   They can be assigned per device for tracking purposes.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license

Comment: Hi H.v.H, I created a test environment in AWS to try and help further and to curb the curiosity.  I just ran the above *EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process*.exe in an RDP session from a Samsung mobile device to WS16' and it returned a CLIENTNAME variable "SM-N920P-7.0".   You have to run the above as the user in the RDP session.  When I google "SM-N920P-7.0" it returns the correct mobile device model.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this same problem.  I tried reading the WTSClientProductId value from the WTSQuerySessionInformation Win32 API function, but it always returns 0x0001, even when called from a session started from an Android tablet.